# What is the minimal set of files for a jetty 9.x base directory for a war file?

Tags: java, web, jetty-9

According to http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html it is possible to manage web applications in base directories in jetty 9.x. The guide explains what can be put inside those and gives an example by pointing to the `demo-base` directory in the binary distribution. However it would have been useful to point out what actually needs to be in such a jetty base in order to make deployment successful, e.g. so that

```
cd /path/to/my-base/
java -jar ~/jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905/start.jar jetty.home=~/jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905/ jetty.base=.
```

succeeds. Putting a minimal valid war file (with only one jsf file) into `/path/to/my-base` or `/path/to/my-base/webapps/` fails with `WARNING: Nothing to start, exiting ...`, although it would make sense to deploy a minimal application or display a helpful warning what needs to be added.

What needs to be added to be able to deploy an application from a separate base directory?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty can make this for you through flags to the start.jar

There's an exmample in the docs, here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.0.v20150612/quickstart-running-jetty.html

"The following commands: create a new base directory; enables a HTTP connector and the web application deployer; copies a demo webapp to be deployed.

Simplified:

```
mkdir /home/me/mybase
cd /home/me/mybase
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --add-to-startd=http,deploy
```

Then copy your war, if you use ROOT.war, it will map to /, and start jetty:

```
cp my.war webapps/ROOT.war
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar
```

Alternatively, if you have docker installed, you can also get the official setup by copying it, like so:

First, have docker download and run jetty, map a directory on the host to the docker container.  I was already mapping webapps, so I just continued to use that mapping.  This removes the container when done (-rm) so it's clean and it starts an interactive bash shell, logging you right into an official barebones jetty container that is ready to deploy wars plopped into the webapps directory (just what we want!)

```
sudo docker run --rm -it -v /home/myuser/jetty/webapps:/var/lib/jetty/webapps jetty:latest /bin/bash
```

If you run and env on the container, you'll see:

```
JETTY_BASE=/var/lib/jetty
```

Just tar this base up, copy the tar to the webapps directory, which is mapped back to the localhost, and exit. (feel free to map

```
root@f99cc00c9c77:/var/lib# tar -czvf ../jetty-base.tar.gz .
root@f99cc00c9c77:/var/lib# cp ../jetty-base.tar.gz jetty/webapps/
root@f99cc00c9c77:/var/lib# exit
```

Back on the localhost, you have a tar of the official jetty base!  The docker container should have stopped on exit, you can test this with sudo docker ps, which should show an empty list (just headers).

Just to finish this off, back on the host, create a base directory (as myuser, not root, of course):

```
mkdir ~/jetty/localbase
cp ~/jetty/jetty-base.tar.gz ~/jetty/localbase/
cd ~/jetty/localbase/
tar xvzf jetty-base.tar.gz
```

Then start it up like before:

```
java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar
```